# How to slice PSDs?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Does anyone have any links/information to share on how to slice PSDs? It has always seemed beyond me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps he should start it with, "As a programming..." :)

Comment: Yes Ben, its html/css programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two tutorials that i found with a simple good search.

They both cover slicing a psd to html. It may not be exactly what you wanted to use a psd for, but it should cover the slicing basics.

http://www.partdigital.com/tutorials/convert-web/

http://net.tutsplus.com/videos/screencasts/converting-a-design-from-psd-to-html/

Answer (score 1):

I saw this post a little while ago. Not sure if this is exactly what you want or not.

**Update ... Whoops sorry accidently forgot to paste the links.**

[What's the best way to go from a Photoshop mockup to semantic HTML and CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487/whats-the-best-way-to-go-from-a-photoshop-mockup-to-semantic-html-and-css)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45903/best-way-to-convert-psd-to-css-html-file

Comment: Definitely missing something :)

Comment: I think it's a comment on an answer.

Comment: Sorry guys. Forgot links. I have added them now. Shouldn't have written when in such a rush.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it can make your job much easier if your PSD file is layered correctly:

http://slicephotoshop.com